# Querying unique column data

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT

Why is only the first row being echoed and not all rows that meet the WHERE condition?

```
$sql="SELECT from_name, to_name FROM private_messages WHERE from_id='$var' OR to_id='$var'" ;
$sql2 = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
echo $row['from_name'];
echo $row['to_name'];
```

Comment: You have to loop through the `mysql_fetch_array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a "while fetch" loop.

Here's an example of the pattern, using the **mysqli** interface.

(NOTE: The PHP **mysql** interface is deprecated. New development should use PDO or mysqli.)

```
 if ($sth = mysqli_query($con, $sql) {
   //echo "#debug: query returned a result set";  
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
     //echo "#debug: fetched next row";
     echo $row['from_name'];
   }
   //echo "#debug: exited while loop, last row already fetched";
 } else {
   //echo "#debug: query execution returned FALSE, handle error";
 }
```

This is the same as the pattern used with the deprecated mysql interface. (Is there some reason you are using that interface? N.B. Do *not* mix mysqli_ and mysql_ functions.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Is the reason for looping because I am querying multiple results?

Comment: The reason for the loop is that the **`fetch`** retrieves one row from the resultset. If we want to get a second row, we need to issue the  **`fetch`** a second time.  Each subsequent `fetch` gets the next row in the resultset.  After we've fetched the last row, our next fetch will return `FALSE`, instead of a row. That's how we know we've gotten all the rows, and that makes it very convenient to use as a condition to exit the loop.